# A Question on a Possible Graph Theory Term

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Let $G$ be a graph and $K_n$ denote the complete graph on $n$ vertices. Given $G$ with $n$ vertices, is there a special term given to the number of edges $G$ needs in order to be a complete graph $K_n$?

As an illustration supposed I have $G$ to be a square that is a graph with 4 vertices and 4 edges. Note that $K_4$ has 6 edges. Is there a special term for 2 (the number of edges $G$ needs in order to become $K_4$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can call it the size of the complement

Comment: Thanks for the answer @user80034. I agree with your answer but are there any specific term that defines "the size of the complement" say for instance "deficiency"?

Comment: Sorry, never heard of one.

Comment: But can I define them as such? Thanks. @user80034

Comment: I find I very often have to define new terms for the undergraduate graph theory lectures that I teach, mostly because I teach in another language than English. Don't be afraid to introduce new terminology. I have found the term deficiency in matching theory, so it might be a good idea to call it size-deficiency instead.

Comment: Now its clear to me. Thanks a lot @user80034. Till next time.